# Appending numpy array as columns onto .npy files without overwriting the original file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, io

I am using the two coding methods below to append two 1-D arrays (macdLine and signalLine) as columns on to .npy files each containing a large 2-D array (c. 50MB each) represented by the 'i'. Either of the methods work fast enough when you have a few files, but are slow when there are many files to work on (may need to work on over 25 files). I have included multi-processing but I still want to improve the speed further. The challenge is that the methods require a file overwrite each time such appending occurs - is there a different way or change in code to achieve faster append operations (and/or without overwriting the original file)?

Method 1:

```
file_path = "%s.npy" % (i)

stackedFile = np.save(i, (np.column_stack(((np.load(file_path)),
                                           macdLine, signalLine))), 
                                           allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=False)
```

Method 2:

```
file_path = "%s.npy" % (i)
    
npyToPandas['8'] = macdLine
npyToPandas['9'] = signalLine
  
stackedFile = np.save(i, 
                      (pd.DataFrame(npyToPandas).to_numpy()), 
                      allow_pickle=True, fix_imports=False)
```

Comment: `npy` consists of header block with info like dtype and shape (about 256 bytes), and then a copy of the array's data_buffer.  That data_buffer is essentially the 1d `ravel` of the array..  When you column stack several arrays you make a whole new array, and the save just writes that new array.  If you use an existing file name, that is replaced.  It doesn't have any sort of append, not even if the array's data layout allowed it.

Comment: With text files it is possible to append rows to an existing file, but columns require a full rewrite.  `npy` is not text, so such a append is even harder.